# Avoid blocking other queries while truncating table

Tags: sql-server

Here's my problem. Let's say I have a long running SELECT query (#1):

```
select * from table1 -- assume this runs for a long time
```

While it's running, I run another SELECT (#2) from the same table. It runs in parallel and finishes in a second:

```
select top 1 * from table1
```

So #2 is not blocked by #1.

Now, let's say I want to run #3, which is truncate and reload of table1:

```
begin tran
   truncate table table1

   insert into table1
   select * from table2
commit
```

#3 is blocked by #1 and has to wait, which is understandable. However, it also puts TABLOCK on the table1 and #2 cannot run either. Essentially #2 becomes blocked by #1.

Question: is there a way to run #3 in a way that is not blocking other queries?
I'd like to see #3 waiting for #1, but #2 still able to run.

I tried to check for locks before running #3, but can't see any locks in sys.dm_tran_locks view. Is there another place where I could see them?

Comment: No. You can't have a truncate sort of sometimes block other queries. Maybe I am not understanding the question but logically it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you want a query to continue to run against a table while you are truncating it and reloading it? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I want the TRUNCATE to be blocked until there are any SELECT queries on the table, but still allow those SELECTs to run. Currently the short queries are blocked by TRUNCATE.

Comment: `Essentially #2 becomes blocked by #1.` - yes, of course! Because it's started after truncation began!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a while, but you could try it like this:

```
begin tran
   CREATE TABLE table1_new <(identical to table1, incl. indexes, keys and triggers)>

   insert into table1_new
   select * from table2

   drop table table1

   RENAME N'table1_new', N'table1', N'OBJECT'
commit
```

You may need to try a higher isolation level to insure that your users don't get any "Object Not Found" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Not sure why it wasn't working for me before, but sys.dm_tran_locks view is the way to go.

Basically, I'm waiting until there are no locks on the table and then start truncate/reload.

```
begin tran

--wait until there are no locks on the table
while exists(
    select 1 from sys.dm_tran_locks
    where resource_database_id = DB_ID()
    and resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1')
)
begin
    waitfor delay '00:00:05'
end

truncate table table1

insert into table1
select * from table2

commit
```

Comment: That is something one really doesn't want to have in a database.

Comment: Haha, sure it looks strange. However, in my scenario data is frequently re-synced from another server and I don't want those sync jobs to block selects. Usually truncate/reload takes only 1-2 seconds, but if it overlaps with long-running select it blocks everything for a very long time and no other queries can be run.

Comment: @IvanStarostin could you elaborate on your comment, please? Is this genuinely something that should be avoided? I realise there is no maximum wait set, but other than that, is this always a bad idea in principle?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine suggested another option, which I ended up using: set LOCK_TIMEOUT before running TRUNCATE.

If it can't lock the table it simply fails. (Of course there should be some mechanism to re-run it later on)

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0
TRUNCATE TABLE table1
```

Hope it helps someone.